# Best way to get a file from remote server and copy to local server using php

Tags: php, download, phpbb, remote-server, localserver

Let's say there is a file on a remote server that can be downloaded without any restrictions, ie. you can put the direct link to the file in your browser and it downloads the file, for example http://www.remotesite.com/video.avi will prompt your browser to download that file. Using php, what is the best way to grab that file and upload it to my local server without the file being downloaded to my PC at all, which is what happens with phpBB if you put a url in the file upload form? An example of the code needed would also be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just use `copy`

```
$source = "http://www.remotesite.com/video.avi";
$dest = "video.avi";
copy($source, $dest);
```

Comment: sounds cool than `file_get` and `file_put` :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$remote_file_contents = file_get_contents('http://remote_url/file/with.extension');
//Get the contents

$local_file_path = 'your/local/path/to/the/file/with.extension';

file_put_contents($local_file_path, $remote_file_contents);
//save the contents of the remote file
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 2):

You can read and write the file without browser download

```
<?php 

$file = 'http://www.remotesite.com/video.avi';

// read the file from remote location
$current = file_get_contents($file);

// create new file name
$name = "path/to/folder/newname.avi";

// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```